# Insert Order no ({id_order}) into order_conf.html Prestashop

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.5

I need to know how I insert the order no. into the corfimation mail (order_conf.html) in Prestashop.

I tried to put in just {id_order} but it just echoing out "{id_order}", not the number.

Anyone?!

My prestaversion is: 1.5.3.1

Answer (score 0):

Got it!
I use {order_name} instead! :)